# NodeJS app (Keystone JS) runs fine when started manually, restarts over and over when started with pm2

Tags: node.js, pm2, keystonejs

I am using Ubuntu 16.04 x 64 and I'm running into an issue -

When I run my Keystone JS app manually by typing in "node keystone", the app runs fine and I can view it in my browser like normal.

However, when I start the app using pm2, the app fails immediately and restarts consecutively.

I think it is because keystonejs has a known "error" that is not a real error, but just a warning when it starts.

From the "keystone-out-0.log" file -

```
Error ...node_modules/bson/build/Release/bson.node: invalid ELF header
```

However, in the "keystone-error-0.log" file, it gives me a different error that does not occur when I run it manually -

```
Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, open '.env'
```

Any one faced anything similar?

Thanks

Comment: Do you have a `.env` file? If not, it's probably worth adding one to see if that fixes it.

Comment: I have one. I ultimately ended up just using forever instead of pm2.  I had no issues with forever.